# how to assign POST values to model's attributes in yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to assign a single POST value to a model's particular attribute. I tried doing following ,

```
$model->que1 = $_POST["id1"];
$data2 = $_POST["id1"] ;
```

first line is not working, instead when I do,

```
echo $model->que1;
```

it show '0'(zero), but when I do,
    echo $data2;

it shows the write value, what's the problem?

here's the entire code for controller action

```
public function actiongetname()
    {
        $model = new Questions();
        $data = 'msg';
        $data2 ="";
        if(isset($_POST["id1"]))
        {
            $model->que1 = $_POST["id1"];
            $data2 = $_POST["id1"] ;

        }
        echo ""+$model->que1;
        echo $data2;
       $this->renderPartial('getname',array ('model'=>$model,'msg'=>$data));
    }
```

Any solution... where am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you add var_dump($_POST); in your action what is the result?

Comment: array (size=1)
  'id1' => string 'asd' (length=3) 

this is the result..

Comment: in Questions model in `rules()` on `que1` what you have?

Comment: no rules are applied. and it is added to the safe list also.

Comment: I am able to get the post values, but not able to assign it to the model's attribute.

Comment: Tried just `echo $model->que1;` or `var_dump($model->que1)`?

Comment: if you try `$model->que1="asd";` and after `echo $model->que1;` ?

Comment: or what return var_dump($model); ?

Comment: @kunal Dethe, this was the output,   string 'ashdah' (length=6)

Comment: Don't know how, but now I got the correct value in $model->que1...
thanks guys.....

Can you tell me how to add new value to the array, without overwriting existing values???

Comment: $model->que1 is array?

Comment: In PHP it should be `echo "" . $model->que1;` and not `echo ""+$model->que1;` or else it will always echo '0'(zero).

Comment: Can you please show us a sample array value of `$model->que1`? and what value do you want to add?

Comment: no no, $model->que1 is not an array, is it possible to globally declare array or CList in yii?

Comment: @kunal, I want to add $model->que1's value to the array,

Comment: It still depends on the type of array. If its a simple PHP array then `array_push($array, $model->que1)` should do it.

Comment: I tried that one, but it was overwriting the existing value, instead of appending... I used CList, and it's method add(), but still the same, is it because I defined that array in that model's function..

Comment: Won't be able to help without some sample code of the array definition and how you are pushing the new value to it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jKmgqC1X, here's the model's code... I have added two variations in one code for simplicity i.e. first using CList and second using array..

Comment: Yes, the overwrite is because of declaring the `$list2 = array();` in the model's function. Every time a new `$list2` empty array variable is created. Please mention in which scope, do you want to use this variable. Depending on that, the scope of the variable can be set.

Comment: I want $list2 array to be updated every time I call that function... meaning array $list2 should maintain it's previous values and should add new element to that array..

Answer (score 0):

You say `echo $model->que1; return '0'(zero)`, this means the que1 property accept integer only and you try to add string in this property and not accepted

```
array (size=1) 'id1' => string 'asd' (length=3)
```